# Iterate over result set keys - is it possible?

Tags: java, json, java-8, restlet

I have a method that takes a database connection, query, and parameters and parses that query into a result set object. This is great but the problem is to get each value out of a result set I have to write one line of code for every row of data I am pulling to then save it in a JSON container. Is there a way to do this systematically so I can automatically parse the data type and create the JSON object based upon the keys fetched from the result set w/o manually specifying the keys?

```
public static JSONArray q2rs2j(Connection connection, String query, List<String> params) throws Exception {
    JSONArray tContainer = new JSONArray();
    PreparedStatement pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    int pit = 1;
    if(params != null) {
        for (String param : params) {
            try {
                double paramAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(param);
                try {
                    int paramAsInt = Integer.parseInt(param);
                    pStatement.setInt(pit, paramAsInt);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    pStatement.setDouble(pit, paramAsDouble);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                pStatement.setString(pit, param);
            }
            pit++;
        }
    }
    ResultSet resultSet = pStatement.executeQuery();
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            // Iterate through KEYS in the resultSet.next() row
            while (hasKey) {
                // Store key Name and key Value in variables - todo: determine data type via try parsing as Int, double, etc
                String thisKeyName = (nextKeyName);
                String thisKeyValue = (nextKeyValue);
                JSONObject tObject = new JSONObject();
                tObject
                    .put(nextKeyName, nextKeyValue);
            }
            tContainer.put(tObject);
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return tContainer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) provides SQL types and java class names.

```
try (ResultSet resultSet = pStatement.executeQuery()) {
    ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int ncols = meta.getColumnCount();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        JSONObject tObject = new JSONObject();
        for (int colno = 1; colno <= ncols; ++colno) {
            String label = meta.getColumnLabel(colno); // Key
            String name = meta.getColumnName(colno);
            String sqlType = meta.getColumnType();
            String type = meta.getColumnClassName();
            String thisKeyName = label;
            Object thisKeyValue = result.getObject(colno);
            if (sqlType.contains("CHAR")) {
                thisKeyVaule = result.getString(colno);
                tObject.put(nextKeyName, nextKeyValue);
            } else if (sqlType.contains("INT")) {
                thisKeyVaule = result.getInt(colno);
                tObject.put(nextKeyName, nextKeyValue);
            } else {
                tObject.put(nextKeyName, nextKeyValue);
            }
        }
        tContainer.put(tObject);
    }
}
```

Using try-with-resources allows automatic closing (useful for Connection, Statement, and ResultSet) - even when on return, break or thrown exception.

Comment: Thanks! I found the meta data method right after I asked but that gives me ideas for how to determine data type as well!